# Swift - ArrayController, when does it get filled with data?

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsarraycontroller

As per title, when I try to print the data from viewDidLoad(), nothing is present in the array controller. But when I print the data from one of the tableview methods there is something in there. So is there a method I can use from the viewcontroller class to check when the tableview and it's data has finished loading?

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var alarmArrayController: NSArrayController!
}
```

**ArrayController's attributes in XCode for ViewController**

[image: Array Controller in XCode]

**ArrayController's Cocoa Bindings in XCode for ViewController**
[image: ArrayController's Cocoa Bindings In XCode For ViewController]

I have this block of code to print my array controller.

```
for object in alarmArrayController.arrangedObjects as! [Alarm] {
    print(object)
    alarmArrayController.removeObject(object)
}
```

It works within the following viewtable method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
```

but not within viewDidAppear() or viewDidLoad()

Comment: Where is details

Comment: What details are you after? I’m interested in when the data is loaded from core data (using core bindings) without having to using a table view method to check if that data exists

Comment: Can you share your Array Controller code? Perhaps the data will be loaded by the time `viewDidAppear()` is called?

Comment: Do you combine `UITableView` and `NSArrayController`? Do you use Cocoa bindings? How did you check the contents of the array controller?

Comment: Hi Chris I’ll share it tonight, but since I’m using core bindings there isn’t much code, I’ll have to update my OP with some screenshots.I have another array controller which is my main view controller but it appears that printing the arrayConttoller from viewdidload() and viewdidappear() presents no data as well.

Comment: What is "core bindings"? Do you mean Cocoa bindings?

Comment: Yes I meant cocoa bindings

Comment: If you want to get the content of the array controller to delete the objects then use a fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your controller an NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate. "A delegate protocol that describes the methods that will be called by the associated fetched results controller when the fetch results have changed." (Apple docs)

Have your class conform to the protocol:

```
class YourViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
```

Set yourself as delegate when you create the data provider object:

```
provider.fetchedResultsControllerDelegate = self
```

Finally, create a class extension as below.

```
extension YourViewController {

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller:
         NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does this solve the issue? Won't `NSArrayController` get confused when you do this?

Comment: My interpretation could be wrong. The OP stated he is "interested in when the data is loaded from core data without having to using a table view method to check if that data exists".

Comment: The question is about `NSArrayController`. Can you bind a table view to a `NSFetchedResultsController` in IB?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So I found my answer while I was updating my post.

What I realised was that at some point during the viewcontroller lifecycle, the data is loaded from core data to my array controller with Cocoa bindings. At what stage during this life cycle I had no idea. What also made things worse was I was looking at the docs for lifecycle of UIViewController not NSViewController.

NSViewController which appear to be **different**
UIViewController
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html

NSViewController
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller

As we can see there are addditional stages within viewDidAppear() for a NSViewController, these are

```
updateViewConstraints()
viewWillLayout()
viewDidLayout()
```

It seems the data isn't loaded until the method viewDidLayout() is called

Comment: `-[NSObjectController fetch:]`: "Beginning with OS X v10.4 the result of this method is deferred until the next iteration of the runloop so that the error presentation mechanism can provide feedback as a sheet.".